# How can I see the numpad option(s) I typed when on a call, after I made the call?

Tags: android-11, call-history, google-pixel-6

Some customer service phone numbers ask the users for type some option (e.g., "press 1 for making an appointment").  How can I see the numpad option(s) I typed when on a call, after I made the call?

I don't see it on the phone history of the built-in phone app:

[image]

I use a Google Pixel 6 with Android 11.

Comment: I don't think it's stored anywhere, nor that I know if there are 3rd-party phone apps that have this functionality.

Comment: Not sure if maybe some call recorder might have this option, but I haven't heard of that yet either (though if they record the "beeps", you might be able to reconstruct from that).